# How can I get the file size in directory traversal?

Tags: c++, qt

How can I get the size of a file when I am using recursion to look at each file?
I'm getting the next error:

> project.exe exited with code -1073741819

```
int dir_size(const QString _wantedDirPath)
{
    long int sizex = 0;
    QFileInfo str_info(_wantedDirPath);
    if (str_info.isDir())
    {
        QDir dir(_wantedDirPath);
        QStringList ext_list;
        dir.setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::Dirs |  QDir::Hidden | QDir::NoSymLinks);
        QFileInfoList list = dir.entryInfoList();

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
        {
            QFileInfo fileInfo = list.at(i);
            if ((fileInfo.fileName() != ".") && (fileInfo.fileName() != ".."))
            {
                sizex += (fileInfo.isDir()) ? this->dir_size(fileInfo.path()) : fileInfo.size():
                QApplication::processEvents();
            }
        } 
    } 

    return sizex;
}
```

Comment: The Q needs to be formed in a better way, Where is it crashing?

Comment: Why don't you add `QDir::NoDotAndDotDot` to the QDir's filter? Then you shouldn't check for the . and .. directories yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its crashing because you are recursively evaluating the same folder again and again. 
The statement `sizex += this->dir_size(fileInfo.path());` calls the same function recursively with the same folder name. 
So your stack keeps growing and eventually out of memory.

`fileInfo.path()` gives the same (parent) folder.

`fileInfo.filePath()` gives the filename with the path

Change it to  `sizex += this->dir_size(fileInfo.filePath());` and that should fix it

Answer (score 8):

Start by cleaning your code a bit.

```
quint64 dir_size(const QString & str)
{
    quint64 sizex = 0;
    QFileInfo str_info(str);
    if (str_info.isDir())
    {
        QDir dir(str);
        QFileInfoList list = dir.entryInfoList(QDir::Files | QDir::Dirs |  QDir::Hidden | QDir::NoSymLinks | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
        {
            QFileInfo fileInfo = list.at(i);
            if(fileInfo.isDir())
            {
                    sizex += dir_size(fileInfo.absoluteFilePath());
            }
            else 
                sizex += fileInfo.size();

        }
    }
    return sizex;
}
```

If you want to keep the ui reactive, do the calcul in a separate thread, call processEvent() at each file is a burden.
You should also use quint64 ( unsigned long long ) to handle big files ( > 2Go )
But, it's not clear where the crash is.

Comment: Somehow `filePath` was causing stack overflow as well. `absoluteFilePath` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
if(fileInfo.isDir())
{
     sizex += this->get_dir_size(fileInfo.path());
     QApplication::processEvents();
}
```

to

```
if(fileInfo.isDir())
{
     sizex += dir_size(fileInfo.path()); //call recursively!
     QApplication::processEvents();
}
```

Why do you call `get_dir_size()` - whatever it is?  You should call `dir_size()` if you want to compute the size recursively.

Comment: because this procedure is member of class, I using "this->" link

Comment: @mcuw: `get_dir_size()` is different, than `dir_size()`. Read the code carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more developed answer for getting a directory's size.  Its results match those of the utility "du" (Disk Usage).

This takes into account that Linux considers the directory entry itself to have size.  It handles symlink/shortcuts correctly in both Linux and Windows (rather than ignoring them!). This also allows the ui "breathe" in a more logical manner than assuming a new directory traversal is the point at which to "rest" for a moment.

```
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32
#include <sys/stat.h>
long getStdFileSize( const std::string &filename )
{
    struct stat stat_buf;
    int rc = stat( filename.c_str(), &stat_buf );
    return rc == 0 ? stat_buf.st_size : -1;
}
#endif

// designed to match the results of the standard
// cross platform utility "du" (Disk Usage)
// compare to du -b [path]
quint64 diskUsage( const QString &absPath, int &itemCount )
{
    static const int UI_REFRESH_FREQ_ITEMS_TRAVERSED( 100 );
    QFileInfo parentInfo( absPath );
    if( parentInfo.exists() ) itemCount++;    
    quint64 totalBytes =
        parentInfo.isSymLink() ?
// handle symlink size correctly
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32
        getStdFileSize( absPath.toStdString() )
#else
        parentInfo.symLinkTarget().length()
#endif
        : parentInfo.size();
    if( parentInfo.isDir() )
    {
        QFileInfoList childInfoList = QDir( absPath ).entryInfoList(
            QDir::Files | QDir::Dirs | QDir::Hidden | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot );
        foreach( const QFileInfo &childInfo, childInfoList )
        {
            totalBytes += diskUsage(
                childInfo.absoluteFilePath(), itemCount );
            // prevent ui lockup, as this can potentially take a long time
            if( (itemCount % UI_REFRESH_FREQ_ITEMS_TRAVERSED)==0 )
                QGuiApplication::processEvents();
        }
    }
    return totalBytes;
}

// convenience overload
quint64 diskUsage( const QString &absPath )
{
    int itemCount=0;
    return diskUsage( absPath, itemCount );
}
```